# Converting negative array values of different data types (string, double, int) into positive

Tags: java, arrays, loops, parseint, negative-number

I have multiple arrays all with different data types (string, double, int) the data type stays the same for the array but each array has a different data type. Ex. Array1 has string values, Array 2 double values, Array 3 int values. All of which contain negative numbers and I want to convert those negative numbers all into positive and put them back into their respective arrays.

I initially thought of using Math.abs but i'd need to make a loop (i assume a for loop) in which I convert all data values to int and then apply Math.abs to those values. But I'm not sure how I can make the loop work for all the different data types as well as placing the new values back into the respective array's in correct order.

I also thought of using Parseint for the conversion but that only applies to strings going to int which doesn't help with the doubles or ints. I need the code to do it all in one universal loop.

Comment: Can you [edit] and share the code you have please ?

Comment: What does it mean for a `String` to have a negative value?

Comment: There is a lack of clarity in your question. The first paragraph seems to say that you seem to want to use the same code to process an `int []`, a `double []`, and a `String []`. The last paragraph suggest they are each a `String []`, but some contain data with elements that represent integer values, and others contain data with elements that represent floating point values.  Can you, please, edit the question to clear this up?  It would help if you include example data from each type of your arrays, and what the results should be.

Comment: You should post your code. We cannot code that for you.

Comment: I recommend method overload.  One method converts an int array to positive int array.  Try that one first.  If you get that one, converting a double array to a positive double array is identical.  As for the String of integers and/or doubles to a String of positive integers and/or is a matter of dropping the - character.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it provides a single method that you can pass an array of Strings, Doubles, or Integers to and get back an array of their absolute values.

```
public <T> T[] abs(T[] objects) {
    if (objects != null) {
        if (objects instanceof Double[] doubles) {
            return (T[]) Arrays.stream(doubles).map(Math::abs).toArray(Double[]::new);
        } else if (objects instanceof Integer[] integers) {
            return (T[]) Arrays.stream(integers).map(Math::abs).toArray(Integer[]::new);
        } else if (objects instanceof String[] strings) {
            return (T[]) Arrays.stream(strings).map(Integer::parseInt).map(Math::abs).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    }

    return objects;
}
```

Using the method would look like this:

```
String [] negativeStrings = new String[] {"-1", "-2", "3", "-6"};
Double [] negativeDoubles = new Double[] {-1.0, -2.3, -4.2, 5.0};
Integer [] negativeIntegers = new Integer[] {-1, -2, 3, -6};

Double[] absDoubles = abs(negativeDoubles);
String[] absStrings = abs(negativeStrings);
Integer[] absIntegers = abs(negativeIntegers);
```

Or, simply:

```
Integer[] absIntegers = abs(new Integer[] {-1, -2, 3, -6});
```